# How to change the keyboard layout in the terminal

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout

In Ubuntu 20.04, how can I change the keyboard layout in the terminal, and without using superuser permissions?

Edit: I do not have a graphical interface, and therefore no access to e.g. `setxkbmap`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The available layouts are listed in `man xkeyboard-config`. Choose one.

#### In a graphical (X11) session

```
setxkbmap -layout "<chosen-layout>"
```

Don't forget the quotes if the layout contains parenthesis.

#### In a virtual console (text-only, TTY) session

Impossible without having root access, unless the sysadmin agrees to let users execute `loadkeys`, as described in [Loadkeys gives permission denied for normal user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85374), in which case you could use

```
loadkeys < <(ckbcomp -layout '<chosen-layout>')
```

Comment: How to make the second one permanent?