# Setting keyboard to UK MacBook Pro in terminal?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

In the settings panel, I can go to keyboard preferences and set the keyboard model to MacBook/MacBook Pro (intl) and the layout to English (UK) - how do I do this in terminal? I've tried messing around with setxkbmap and loadkeys, but I can't get either of these to work properly. Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the keyboard layout in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287390/how-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-in-the-terminal)

Comment: @24601 How do I get the exact name of the layout though?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get keyboard layout (language) in terminal (console, command-line)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973257/how-to-get-keyboard-layout-language-in-terminal-console-command-line) (to get the exact name of the keyboard layout)

Answer (score 1):

> sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl

Change the section

> // Map Ctrl to the left Alt key, Alt to the left Win key,
> // and Super

whey it says "replace key " with

> replace key  { [ ISO_Level3_Shift ] };

On your shell configuration script write

> stty intr 0xA2

Open Tweaks
On Aditional Layout Options -> Ctrl , mark "Map Ctrl to the left Alt key, Alt to the left Win key, and Super to the left Ctrl key."

Then on gnome-terminal remap the copy and paste to ctrl c and ctrl v that shoyuld be "Ctrl C" "Ctrl V"

Then move physically your keys to make sense